# Manually change the status of the approval workflow after its completion

Tags: workflow, approval

Is it possible to change manually the status of the completed workflow from "Approved" to "Rejected"? The final person in the list of approvers made a mistake and approved a contract, which has to be rejected. Is there a way to undo this action now?
Thank you,
Polina

Comment: I would personally just reinitiate the workflow and have the first person reject it, stating that this is rejected per the boss man so the workflow history is accurate

Comment: Many thanks, Eric! Haven't thought about this solution. Works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 2):

I would personally just restart the approval workflow so that the first person rejects the item. This way the workflow status and history accurately reflect the intent should it ever need reviewed.